# Not able to enable Native memory tracking in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, jvm

I am trying to enable NMT in my spring boot application like this

```
 java -jar -Dlogging.config=log4j2.xml -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary application.jar
```

However, I get a warning

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Native Memory Tracking did not setup properly, using wrong launcher?
```

How can I enable NMT for an application running on embedded tomcat?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change the order of arguments:

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -Dlogging.config=log4j2.xml -jar application.jar
```

This is a pecularity of `java` launcher. `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking` must be handled both by the launcher and by the JVM in order to take effect. However, the launcher stops processing arguments as soon as it sees a [terminal option](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/95937fc2a05e/src/java.base/share/native/libjli/args.c#l446). `-jar` is one them.

Comment: Might be worth saying why this matters. ;) +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey Agreed. Added the paragraph. At the same time I personally think this is a bug. Arguments are processed twice, but the processing logic is not consistent between the launcher and the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

If you run one JVM per environment (e.g. in container), `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is the place for flags:

`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -Dlogging.config=log4j2.xml java -jar application.jar`